# Python/Pandas fill NaN values

Tags: dataframe

Out[2]:
GROUP  A    B
0   1.0  2.0  5.0
1   1.0  5.0  7.0
2   2.0  3.0  6.0
3   2.0  NaN  NaN
4   2.0  NaN  NaN
5.  2.0  8.0  4.0

Desired output:

Out[2]:
GROUP A   B
0    1.0 2.0 5.0
1    1.0 5.0 7.0
2    2.0 3.0 6.0
3    2.0 6.0 7.0
4    2.0 7.0 8.0
5.   2.0   8.0  4.0

Comment: You need to provide at least some explanation of your problem (not just desired output), preferably provide some of your code so that people can understand your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
blocks = df['GROUP'].ne(df['GROUP'].shift()).cumsum()
df['END'] = df['END'].fillna(df.fillna(1).groupby(blocks)['END'].cumsum()) 
df['START'] = df['START'].fillna(df['END'].shift())
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in vectorized solution for your case, but you can solve it by iterating and processing each `NaN` section at a time.

```
# initialize starting and ending values
df['START'] = df['START'].mask(df['START'].isna(), df['END'].shift())
df['END'] = df['END'].mask(df['END'].isna(), df['START'].shift(-1))

while df['END'].isna().any():
    i = df['END'].loc[df['END'].isna()].index[0] # get idx of first NaN
    k = df['END'].loc[i:].loc[~df['END'].isna()].index[0] # get idx of next valid
    if df.loc[i, 'GROUP'] != df.loc[k, 'GROUP']:
        # you did not specify what to do in case a group started or ended in NaN
        # this will replace with a temp string and later replace back to NaN
        df.loc[i:k, 'START':'END'] = 'temp'
        continue
    
    n = k - i + 1
    start = df.loc[i, 'START'] # get value
    end = df.loc[k, 'END'] # get value
    delta = (end - start) / n
    df.loc[i:k, 'START':'END'] = [
        [start + row * delta, start + (row + 1) * delta]
        for row in range(n)
    ]

df = df.replace('temp', np.nan)
```

Output

```
   GROUP  START  END
0      1    2.0  5.0
1      1    5.0  7.0
2      2    3.0  6.0
3      2    6.0  7.0
4      2    7.0  8.0
5      2    8.0  4.0
```

Notice that some error handling would be needed to account for the first or last row of the dataframe being `NaN`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes so much sense the only issue im getting is on this line: k = df['time_stamp_end'].loc[i:].loc[~df['time_stamp_end'].isna()].index[0], the i keep getting index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 size 0

Comment: @stackoverlord That is the issue I explained at the end of the answer, is the last value of that column `NaN` ?

Comment: I fixed it, it was because of the last value NaN. Gracias wey!

Comment: Un crack! nose cómo hiciste una solución tan concisa!

Comment: @stackoverlord did you test ansev's solution? I can't tell if that is a full solution or just a suggestion, but if that works then THAT would be concise